# Highchart, is it possible to have a 'for loop' inside 'series' section?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, highcharts

Currently I'm using `Stacked and grouped column` highchart which can see the code [in this jsfiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/b72e0vh4/8/) My goal is to loop inside a `series` section so that I can generate the stacked bar. I'm using laravel framework for this system.

**Current code (jsfiddle)**

```
    series: [
    {
        name: 'John',
        color: 'olive',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: '2014',
        xAxis: 1
    },
    ...
```

**Attempted code (is this the way to do it?)**

```
var temp = ["john", "olive", "[5, 3, 4, 7, 2]", "2014", 1];

series: [
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    {
        name: temp[0],
        color: temp[1],
        data: temp[2],
        stack: temp[3],
        xAxis: temp[4]            

    },
}
```

**EDIT reply for @Lucky Saini answer**

[image]

Comment: can you add integer value `1` to `"1"` double quotes? Because this is working I double checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not write the code in this way in array, but you can create an IIFE function:

```
    series: (function() {
        var series = [],
            temp = ["john", "olive", "[5, 3, 4, 7, 2]", "2014", 1];

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            series.push({
                name: temp[0],
                color: temp[1],
                data: JSON.parse(temp[2]),
                stack: temp[3],
                xAxis: temp[4]

            });
        }

        return series;
    }())
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/01qzg4e5/

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a for loop inside a method/function.

Instead, you can loop it outside the function and store that in the array. And use that array by passing it to the series parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to construct series array in php and use [json encode php array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
and then parse the json data in javascript using [JSON Parse in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Another way is, in your .blade file 
    `series: <?php echo json_encode(<php array here>) ?>`

let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: I did `series: <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>`...I am not sure why i got `Undefined variable` error. In my controller, i put `$arr = "[{name: 'John',
                color: 'olive',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
                stack: '2014',
                xAxis: 1}]"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this approach to add data in `series` variable using for loop.

```
var temp = ["john", "olive", "[5, 3, 4, 7, 2]", "2014", 1];

series = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    item = {
        name: temp[0],
        color: temp[1],
        data: temp[2],
        stack: temp[3],
        xAxis: temp[4]            

    };

    series.push(item);
}

console.log(series);
```

Comment: i have edited my question, i have an error by following the code